# wordpress - Convert url query string to static

Tags: url-rewriting, wordpress

Can anyone please help me understand if there is any standard function or process in wordpress that can be used to convert dynamic query strings to static just like how wordpress converts dynamic urls into SEF urls on setting permalinks in wp-admin.

I am developing a plugin based on woocommerce where the user will be provided with a dynamic link. This leads to another page where the query string is extracted using $_GET.

Now I am looking to make this happen without dynamic format in url but static/SEFformat.

**Updating my question:**

Below is the code I have been trying in my plugin and not able to see the change the url format.

```
function dashboard_messages_url_rewrite() {
global $wp_rewrite;
add_rewrite_tag('%cid%', '([^&]+)');
add_rewrite_rule('^conversations/([0-9]+)/', 'index.php?page_id=3242&cid=$matches[1]', 'top');

$wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);
}
add_action('init', 'dashboard_messages_url_rewrite', 10, 0);
```

for example if the url is generated as

`http://example.com/conversations/?cid=2234`

I want it to be converted by wordpress as below

`http://example.com/conversations/2234`

Hope this will help to understand what I have been trying. Thanks

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I tried working with what was explained in your reference question's answer, but it did not work for me. Now, can I continue here or comment on the other question's answer?

Comment: What exactly have you tried? Please edit your question with the code.

Comment: Every time you programmatically create new rewrite rules in Wordpress, using rewrite functions or when adding custom post types for instance, you need to flush the permalinks. To do so, simply go to permalinks settings page in your WP admin and hit the save button. This will be enough to flush the rules. Try that and let me know if it works now, please.

Comment: I tried the permalinks saving but it did not work.

Comment: Your rule is missing the final `?` to make the last slash optional. I've run some tests here and after simply adding the question mark it worked. Try that and let me know what happens. Don't forget to save your permalink settings after change the code.

Comment: Can you please let me know in which part of the rule this `?` should be added...

Comment: Here: `'^conversations/([0-9]+)/?'`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Gustavo! It has solved the problem.

Comment: Awesome! I've compiled my comments as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is missing the final `?` to make the last slash optional. After adding the question mark, your redirect should work. The function call will look like this:

```
add_rewrite_rule('^conversations/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?page_id=3242&cid=$matches[1]', 'top');
```

Also, every time you programmatically create new rewrite rules in Wordpress, using rewrite functions or when adding custom post types, for instance, you need to flush the permalinks. To do so, simply go to permalink settings page in your WP admin and hit the save button. This will be enough to flush the rules.